# How to get multiple maximum count values in access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following input table:

[image]

My goal is to extract records that have the highest CountOfObject_Type for each respondent at each date.

From the first two records I want to get the first record because it has the highest count of object Type.

The second will be excluded because Date, Respondent ID and country are same as the first record.

This is the output I'm expecting:

[image]

I have writen the following query but it returns only one value(maximum). But I want to get the multiple maximum values that are grouped by date, respondent ID and Country.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: And pls add the code of the query you attempted.

Comment: According to your text you want Country included in the grouping.  But according to your example output, you ignore Country (because on 30/06/2016 you have only 3 HOUSE FRANCE and not 3 HOUSE GERMANY as well!)  Which is correct?  The text or the example?

Comment: both are right. In that case respondent id is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the biggest problems with Access is that it lacks a ROW_NUMBER() function, with OVER() and PARTITION BY().  This combination makes light work of "SELECT whole Record where one field is Highest/First in group" type queries.  In Access we need a workaround.  Unfortunately your data has no natural ranking identifier.  Therefore we have to create one in the order that your data appears to be ordered (Dat, Respondent_ID, Country and Object_Type).  Since you have not answered as to whether country should be included in the grouping, I give two versions.

No Country in Group:

```
SELECT fD.Dat, fD.Respondent_ID, fd.Object_Type, fD.Country, 
fD.CountOfObject_Type 
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, Dat, Respondent_ID, 
    MAX(CountOfObject_Type) AS MaxCount 
    FROM
        (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable 
        WHERE (Dat = g.Dat AND Respondent_ID & Country & Object_Type 
    <=  g.Respondent_ID & g.Country & g.Object_Type) 
        OR (Dat < g.Dat)) AS ID, 
    g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID,g.Country,g.Object_Type, g.CountOfObject_Type
    FROM YourTable g 
    ORDER BY g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID, g.Country, g.Object_type) o
    GROUP BY Dat, Respondent_ID) mC
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable 
    WHERE (Dat = g.Dat AND Respondent_ID & Country & Object_Type 
    <=  g.Respondent_ID & g.Country & g.Object_Type) 
    OR (Dat < g.Dat)) AS ID, 
    g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID,g.Country,g.Object_Type, g.CountOfObject_Type
    FROM YourTable g 
    ORDER BY g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID, g.Country, g.Object_type) fD
ON mC.MinID = fD.Id
```

With Country in Grouping:

```
SELECT fD.Dat, fD.Respondent_ID, fd.Object_Type, fD.Country, 
fD.CountOfObject_Type 
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, Dat, Respondent_ID, Country,
    MAX(CountOfObject_Type) AS MaxCount 
    FROM
        (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable 
        WHERE (Dat = g.Dat AND Respondent_ID & Country & Object_Type 
    <=  g.Respondent_ID & g.Country & g.Object_Type) 
        OR (Dat < g.Dat)) AS ID, 
    g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID,g.Country,g.Object_Type, g.CountOfObject_Type
    FROM YourTable g 
    ORDER BY g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID, g.Country, g.Object_type) o
    GROUP BY Dat, Respondent_ID, Country) mC
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable 
    WHERE (Dat = g.Dat AND Respondent_ID & Country & Object_Type 
    <=  g.Respondent_ID & g.Country & g.Object_Type) 
    OR (Dat < g.Dat)) AS ID, 
    g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID,g.Country,g.Object_Type, g.CountOfObject_Type
    FROM YourTable g 
    ORDER BY g.Dat, g.Respondent_ID, g.Country, g.Object_type) fD
ON mC.MinID = fD.Id
```